# Unable to get authentication ticket

Tags: asp.net, authentication

In my asp.net application, I am using Aspose.PDF for merging 2 pdf documents. I get the PDF documents from a third party tool and then merge using Aspose.

Problem is when I am running the solution, it works fine, but when I publish the solution and then run it from IIS, it gives me the error: "Error getting authentication ticket."

Please help. If any other details are reqd, pls do let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the exact exception that you get? Can you copy the exception details and paste them in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running the application is full trust mode? The Aspose.Pdf for .NET only works in full trust environment. Please see the details here: http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/declaration.html. Please make sure that you deploy the application in full trust environment.

Disclosure: I work as a developer evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying back. The application is set in Full Trust. 
I have IIS7 and checked the .NET Trust levels. Is there anywhere else I should check?

Comment: In that case, we'll have to test the issue at our end. You may share the input files using our forum for testing purpose: http://goo.gl/EHTpX. Also, one thing you can do at the moment is try using the latest version. Once we get sample input files, we'll investigate and guide you accordingly.